# Call to a member function MoveNext() on array after updating OSCommerce code to Zen Cart

Tags: php, arrays, oscommerce, zen-cart

I have a code segment from OSCommerce like

```
while ( $product_array = tep_db_fetch_array($this->products_sql)) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Further to a request for more information, the full function leading prior to the code in question is shown below.

```
function get_next_product() {
    global $Count, $shoppingCart;

    if ($Count && ($this->Products >= $Count)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    $product = NULL;
    while ($product_array = tep_db_fetch_array($this->products_sql)) {
        $GLOBALS['exporter_module']->checkUsedMemory();
        $GLOBALS['shoppingCart']->processProductData($product_array);

        foreach ($this->values as $valueName => $valuesArr) {
            $product_array[$valueName] = $valuesArr[$product_array['products_id']];
        }

        $product = $product_array;
        $product_array['id'] = $product_array['products_id'];
        $product['id'] = $product_array['products_id'];
        $product['quantity'] = $product_array['products_quantity'];

        // get special price
        $special_price = $this->getSpecial($product_array);

        if (null !== $special_price['price']) {
            $product['price'] = $special_price['price'];
            $_product['is_special'] = 1;
        } else {
            $product['price'] = $product_array['products_price'];
            $product['is_special'] = 0;
            // Include in Base Price, When Priced by Attributes.
            if (isset($product['products_priced_by_attribute'])
                    && $product['products_priced_by_attribute'] == 1
                    && $product['products_price'] == 0
                    && $product['products_price_sorter'] != 0)  {

             $product['price'] = $product['products_price_sorter'];
             $product_array['products_price'] = $product['products_price_sorter'];
            }
        }
}
```

Based on information found [on the zen cart wiki](https://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Developers_-_Porting_modules_from_osC) I changed that for Zen Cart to

```
while (!$product_array->EOF) {
    // do some stuff
$product_array->MoveNext();
}
```

and now get a Fatal Error: Call to a member function MoveNext() on array
$this->products_sql is the content of a function found elsewhere in the same file. Yet even this isn't the actual sql query.

```
function get_products() 
 {
    $this->products_sql = $this->select_products($this->options['categories'], $this->options['language'], $this->options['quantities'], $this->options['withzero'], $this->options['stockout'], $this->options['sub']);    
 }
```

I figured it would help if you knew what $this->products_sql used in the original code contained, so the var_dump is shown below.

```
object(queryFactoryResult)#47 (10) {
["EOF"]=>
bool(false)
["cursor"]=>
int(0)
["fields"]=>
array(49) {
  ["products_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_type"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_quantity"]=>
  string(2) "30"
  ["products_model"]=>
  string(8) "MG200MMS"
  ["products_image"]=>
  string(19) "matrox/mg200mms.gif"
  ["products_price"]=>
  string(8) "299.9900"
  ["products_virtual"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["products_date_added"]=>
  string(19) "2003-11-03 12:32:17"
  ["products_last_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2004-04-26 23:57:34"
  ["products_date_available"]=>
  NULL
  ["products_weight"]=>
  string(2) "23"
  ["products_status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_tax_class_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["manufacturers_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_ordered"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["products_quantity_order_min"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_quantity_order_units"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_priced_by_attribute"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["product_is_free"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["product_is_call"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["products_quantity_mixed"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["product_is_always_free_shipping"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["products_qty_box_status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_quantity_order_max"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["products_sort_order"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["products_discount_type"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["products_discount_type_from"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["products_price_sorter"]=>
  string(8) "299.9900"
  ["master_categories_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["products_mixed_discount_quantity"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["metatags_title_status"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["metatags_products_name_status"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["metatags_model_status"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["metatags_price_status"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["metatags_title_tagline_status"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["language_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["products_name"]=>
  string(15) "Matrox G200 MMS"
  ["products_description"]=>
  string(1159) "Reinforcing its position as a multi-monitor trailblazer, Matrox Graphics Inc. has once again developed the most flexible and highly advanced solution in the industry. Introducing the new Matrox G200 Multi-Monitor Series; the first graphics card ever to support up to four DVI digital flat panel displays on a single 8&quot; PCI board.<br /><br />With continuing demand for digital flat panels in the financial workplace, the Matrox G200 MMS is the ultimate in flexible solutions. The Matrox G200 MMS also supports the new digital video interface (DVI) created by the Digital Display Working Group (DDWG) designed to ease the adoption of digital flat panels. Other configurations include composite video capture ability and onboard TV tuner, making the Matrox G200 MMS the complete solution for business needs.<br /><br />Based on the award-winning MGA-G200 graphics chip, the Matrox G200 Multi-Monitor Series provides superior 2D/3D graphics acceleration to meet the demanding needs of business applications such as real-time stock quotes (Versus), live video feeds (Reuters & Bloombergs), multiple windows applications, word processing, spreadsheets and CAD."
  ["products_url"]=>
  string(45) "www.matrox.com/mga/products/g200_mms/home.cfm"
  ["products_viewed"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["categories_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["categories_name"]=>
  string(14) "Graphics Cards"
  ["categories_description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["languages_name"]=>
  string(7) "English"
  ["languages_code"]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["manufacturers_name"]=>
  string(6) "Matrox"
  ["manufacturers_image"]=>
  string(37) "manufacturers/manufacturer_matrox.gif"
  ["date_added"]=>
  string(19) "2003-12-23 03:18:19"
  ["last_modified"]=>
  NULL
}
["is_cached"]=>
bool(false)
["result"]=>
array(0) {
}
["result_random"]=>
NULL
["limit"]=>
NULL
["resource"]=>
object(mysqli_result)#52 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(53)
  ["lengths"]=>
  array(53) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(1)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
    [3]=>
    int(8)
    [4]=>
    int(19)
    [5]=>
    int(8)
    [6]=>
    int(1)
    [7]=>
    int(19)
    [8]=>
    int(19)
    [9]=>
    int(0)
    [10]=>
    int(2)
    [11]=>
    int(1)
    [12]=>
    int(1)
    [13]=>
    int(1)
    [14]=>
    int(1)
    [15]=>
    int(1)
    [16]=>
    int(1)
    [17]=>
    int(1)
    [18]=>
    int(1)
    [19]=>
    int(1)
    [20]=>
    int(1)
    [21]=>
    int(1)
    [22]=>
    int(1)
    [23]=>
    int(1)
    [24]=>
    int(1)
    [25]=>
    int(1)
    [26]=>
    int(1)
    [27]=>
    int(8)
    [28]=>
    int(1)
    [29]=>
    int(1)
    [30]=>
    int(1)
    [31]=>
    int(1)
    [32]=>
    int(1)
    [33]=>
    int(1)
    [34]=>
    int(1)
    [35]=>
    int(1)
    [36]=>
    int(1)
    [37]=>
    int(15)
    [38]=>
    int(1159)
    [39]=>
    int(45)
    [40]=>
    int(1)
    [41]=>
    int(1)
    [42]=>
    int(1)
    [43]=>
    int(14)
    [44]=>
    int(0)
    [45]=>
    int(7)
    [46]=>
    int(2)
    [47]=>
    int(1)
    [48]=>
    int(1)
    [49]=>
    int(6)
    [50]=>
    int(37)
    [51]=>
    int(19)
    [52]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(2)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
["link"]=>
object(mysqli)#9 (19) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(2)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50011)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(11)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["server_info"]=>
  string(6) "5.6.35"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(50635)
  ["stat"]=>
  string(137) "Uptime: 48210  Threads: 6  Questions: 20698  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 114  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 64  Queries per second avg: 0.429"
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(398)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
}
["sql_query"]=>
string(693) "SELECT p.*, pd.*, cd.*, l.name as languages_name, l.code as languages_code,pc.categories_id,   m.*  from products p LEFT JOIN products_description pd ON p.products_id = pd.products_id LEFT JOIN products_to_categories pc ON p.products_id=pc.products_id LEFT JOIN categories_description cd ON pc.categories_id=cd.categories_id AND cd.language_id = pd.language_id LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON p.manufacturers_id=m.manufacturers_id LEFT JOIN languages l on pd.language_id=l.languages_id  WHERE  1  AND pd.language_id IN (1) AND p.products_price > 0  AND pc.categories_id IN (1,4)  AND (p.manufacturers_id IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) OR p.manufacturers_id IS NULL)       ORDER BY  p.products_id  ASC  "
}
```

Comment: If @scott-c-wilson sees this, I'd put money on him knowing the answer. #ZC-Guru

Comment: StevePrice: You win! #ZC-Guru

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `$this->products_sql` is an actual SELECT string, right?  (If not, please post more context.)   Assuming so, your code should be:

```
$this->products_sql = "SELECT bla bla bla"; 
$product_array = $db->Execute($this->products_sql); 
while (!$product_array->EOF) {
   // do some stuff
   // product_array fields are $product_array->fields['field1'], etc. 
   $product_array->MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: Not a SELECT string per se. I'll add additional info to the original question as too much to fit in a comment.

Comment: Updated with the full function, and the function that populates $this->products_sql

Comment: You need to figure out the query that `get_products` is running, and then set $this->products_sql to whatever that is.

Comment: That would be the query shown at the end of the var dump wouldn't it?

Comment: I would guess so.

Comment: FYI, I figured it out. 
$product_array = $this->products_sql;
while (!$product_array->EOF) {
//do stuff
$product_array->MoveNext();
}

I'm getting a few "Cannot use object of type queryFactoryResult as array" errors now where ->fields needs adding.

Comment: Please post your work in progress as an edit to your answer (remove the array dump but show the value of $this->products_sql being set) - it's hard to read code in comments.